# get bonded balance using API

Tags: polkadot-js, api

This is how to get the free balance of an account:

```
api.query.system.account(stash_account_address).data.free.toBigInt()
```

How to get the bonded balance instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a bunch of metadata about the a users staking configuration, you can do:

```
api.derive.staking.account(stash_account_address)
```

This returns an object like:

```
"{
  \"nextSessionIds\": [],
  \"sessionIds\": [],
  \"accountId\": \"..\",
  \"controllerId\": \"..\",
  \"exposure\": {
    \"total\": 0,
    \"own\": 0,
    \"others\": []
  },
  \"nominators\": [ ... ],
  \"rewardDestination\": {
    \"staked\": null
  },
  \"stakingLedger\": {
    \"stash\": \"...\",
    \"total\": 223370014049,
    \"active\": 223370014049,
    \"unlocking\": [],
    \"claimedRewards\": []
  },
  \"stashId\": \"...\",
  \"validatorPrefs\": {
    \"commission\": 0,
    \"blocked\": false
  },
  \"redeemable\": \"0x00000000000000000000000000000000\"
}"
```

In this case `stakingLedger.total` will be the total balance bonded in Staking. `stakingLedger.active` will be the amount actively bonded, and `stakingLedger.unlocking` will note whatever amounts are waiting to be unbonded.

If you want to query this stuff directly, you need to look inside the `staking` pallet:

```
api.query.staking.ledger(stash_account_address)
```

Where you will get just:

```
"{
  \"stash\": \"EGVQCe73TpFyAZx5uKfE1222XfkT3BSKozjgcqzLBnc5eYo\",
  \"total\": 1899823370014049,
  \"active\": 1899823370014049,
  \"unlocking\": [],
  \"claimedRewards\": [ ... ]
}"
```